# Javascript: Defining Global Variable

Tags: javascript

I know this is something really fundamental, but I am not quiet getting it. I am trying to define a variable `abc` as global variable and then printing it out at the end. But it returns `undefined`. Printing it inside works just fine.

```
var abc;
var data;
$.get('http://localhost:3000/test.php', function (data, status) {
    console.log(status);
    abc = data;
    console.log(abc);  //printing it here works fine
});

console.log(abc);  //printing it here returns undefined
```

Comment: .get does not block. Read up on callbacks.

Comment: You are making an asynchronous call. As such the value will not be defined outside of the get call until after the get returns.

Comment: Change the first line to `var abc=5;` and see what happens. And change one of your `console.log()`'s to `console.log("123" + abc);` to figure out which one is actually working.